# How to swap sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence, swap

I am very new for R programming and I have tried to swap the sequence but I am not sure that there are functions in R or other ways to swap the sequence or not.
I have vector data like this

```
yy <- c(21,22,8,24)
```

Then, I want to swap between 2 no. It starts from the first index and swapping with second and third index respectively. For example, `21` swaps with `22`, `21` swaps with `8`, `21` swaps with `24`

The result should look as follows

```
22,21,8,24

8,22,21,24

24,22,8,21

21,8,22,24

21,24,8,22

22,21,24,8
```

Comment: do you need all combinations?

Answer (score 3):

We could use `embed`.  It is not clear whether duplicate values are allowed in a single row

```
embed(c(yy, yy, yy), 6)[, 1:4]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   22   21   24    8
#[2,]    8   22   21   24
#[3,]   24    8   22   21
#[4,]   21   24    8   22
#[5,]   22   21   24    8
#[6,]    8   22   21   24
#[7,]   24    8   22   21
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible, akrun! Yet another base function I've never heard of, to the rescue!

Comment: probably i am not correct but it doesnt seem that there is swapping here.

Answer (score 2):

```r
do.call(Map, c(list(f = function(a, b) replace(yy, a, yy[b])), 
               asplit(combn(length(yy), 2), 1)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 22 22  8 24
# [[2]]
# [1]  8 22  8 24
# [[3]]
# [1] 24 22  8 24
# [[4]]
# [1] 21  8  8 24
# [[5]]
# [1] 21 24  8 24
# [[6]]
# [1] 21 22 24 24
```

Walk-through:

- Produce a combination of all indices to swap:

  ```r
  combn(length(yy), 2)
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  # [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
  # [2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
  ```
- `asplit(..., 1)` splits that matrix into each row.
- `function(...) replace(...)` swaps the two elements of the vector.
- `Map` applies a function (`f=`) to each element (paired) in vectors/lists
- but because we need to generate these lists dynamically, I use `do.call` to create the list of args

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
t(combn(length(yy),2, function(y) replace(yy, rev(y), yy[y])))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   22   21    8   24
[2,]    8   22   21   24
[3,]   24   22    8   21
[4,]   21    8   22   24
[5,]   21   24    8   22
[6,]   21   22   24    8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option with `for` loops

```
out <- list()
for (i in 1:(length(yy)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):length(yy)) {
    out[[length(out)+1]] <- replace(yy,c(i,j),yy[c(j,i)])
  }
}
```

which gives

```
> out
[[1]]
[1] 22 21  8 24

[[2]]
[1]  8 22 21 24

[[3]]
[1] 24 22  8 21

[[4]]
[1] 21  8 22 24

[[5]]
[1] 21 24  8 22

[[6]]
[1] 21 22 24  8
```

---

If you want it work as a function:

```
f <- function(yy) {
out <- list()
for (i in 1:(length(yy)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):length(yy)) {
    out[[length(out)+1]] <- replace(yy,c(i,j),yy[c(j,i)])
  }
}
out
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to do similar swap operation between two vectors, you can try the code below

```
yy <- c(21, 22, 8, 24)
xx <- c(5, 7, 9, 12)

out <- list()
u <- c(yy, xx)
for (i in seq_along(yy)) {
  for (j in length(yy) + seq_along(xx)) {
    z <- replace(u, c(i, j), u[c(j, i)])
    out[[length(out) + 1]] <- list(yy = z[seq_along(yy)], xx = z[-seq_along(yy)])
  }
}
```

such that

```
> out
[[1]]
[[1]]$yy
[1]  5 22  8 24

[[1]]$xx
[1] 21  7  9 12


[[2]]
[[2]]$yy
[1]  7 22  8 24

[[2]]$xx
[1]  5 21  9 12


[[3]]
[[3]]$yy
[1]  9 22  8 24

[[3]]$xx
[1]  5  7 21 12


[[4]]
[[4]]$yy
[1] 12 22  8 24

[[4]]$xx
[1]  5  7  9 21


[[5]]
[[5]]$yy
[1] 21  5  8 24

[[5]]$xx
[1] 22  7  9 12


[[6]]
[[6]]$yy
[1] 21  7  8 24

[[6]]$xx
[1]  5 22  9 12


[[7]]
[[7]]$yy
[1] 21  9  8 24

[[7]]$xx
[1]  5  7 22 12


[[8]]
[[8]]$yy
[1] 21 12  8 24

[[8]]$xx
[1]  5  7  9 22


[[9]]
[[9]]$yy
[1] 21 22  5 24

[[9]]$xx
[1]  8  7  9 12


[[10]]
[[10]]$yy
[1] 21 22  7 24

[[10]]$xx
[1]  5  8  9 12


[[11]]
[[11]]$yy
[1] 21 22  9 24

[[11]]$xx
[1]  5  7  8 12


[[12]]
[[12]]$yy
[1] 21 22 12 24

[[12]]$xx
[1] 5 7 9 8


[[13]]
[[13]]$yy
[1] 21 22  8  5

[[13]]$xx
[1] 24  7  9 12


[[14]]
[[14]]$yy
[1] 21 22  8  7

[[14]]$xx
[1]  5 24  9 12


[[15]]
[[15]]$yy
[1] 21 22  8  9

[[15]]$xx
[1]  5  7 24 12


[[16]]
[[16]]$yy
[1] 21 22  8 12

[[16]]$xx
[1]  5  7  9 24
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is work and it is what I want.  so, in case we need to change dataset, can we apply this as a function?

Comment: in case I have more than 1 vector e.g. xx <- c(5,7,9,10) and I would like to exchange number between vectors. Can I also apply this for loop? Any advice?

Comment: @sNooze How would you like to exchange number between vectors? Could you show the expected output of that case and explain a bit?

Comment: For example, I have 2 vectors. So, I want to exchange xx[1] to every index in vector yy. 
while xx shows yy index instead. Until finish all index for both vectors

yy <- c(21,22,8,24)
xx <- c(5,7,9,12)

expected result:
5,22,8,24

21,7,9,12

21,5,8,24

22,7,9,12

21,22,5,24

8,7,9,12

21,22,8,5

24,7,9,12

7,22,8,24

5,21,9,12

21,7,8,24

5,22,9,12

21,22,7,24

5,8,9,12

21,22,8,7

5,24,9,12